# start function when div appear

Tags: javascript, html

In my HTML file I have a `div` with `id="print"` and when this `div` appears on the screen I would like to start function `print()`. How can I do this?

```
<div id="print">
</div>

function check(){
//check appear div
}

function print(){
//print data
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `when this div appear`? That suggests the `div` is initially hidden, but it's hard to be certain.

Comment: Is the `div` hidden or do you mean when the `div` is shown in the window?

Comment: no it is not hidden, I mean when is shown in the window ... I use reveal.js and you can create slides and when certain slide is shown I want to start print()

Comment: @user3357400, is there any type of event to do that in reveal.js?  Have you looked into the documentation?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

like @TheShinyTuxedo suggested this can be resolved by adding a script right after the div is rendered.

look like that:

```
<div id="print">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   print();
</script>
```